# Implementing Firebase's GoogleSignIn results in 2 iterations of the same view controller popping up, one on top of the other

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-signin

Essentially, whenever a user clicks on a button that transitions them to a screen where they can sign in using their google credentials, the end-result is that 2 of the same exact screen pop up. The second screen has a useable button, which functions perfectly, however when they use the button I've implemented, which allows them to transition to previous screens in the ViewController stack, the result is that the application crashes. Now, I have no idea why there are even 2 iterations of this view controller in the first place, is there anyone that can help diagnose my issue? I will attach the code for the view controller below, however I must mention that this same behaviour is observed with only the "    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;" being preserved (I.E. If I delete all other google sign in related functions, it still displays this behaviour). The code:

```
#import "FifthViewController.h"
@import Firebase;
@import GoogleSignIn;

@interface FifthViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *googleLoginBackButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GIDSignInButton *googleLoginButton;

@end

@implementation FifthViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    _googleLoginBackButton.layer.cornerRadius = _googleLoginBackButton.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.googleLoginBackButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
    self.googleLoginBackButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [_googleLoginBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonHighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [_googleLoginBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_googleLoginBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
    _googleLoginButton.style = kGIDSignInButtonStyleWide;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)backButtonHighlightBorder
{
    _googleLoginBackButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.61 green:0.00 blue:0.02 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
}

- (void)backButtonUnhighlightBorder
{
    _googleLoginBackButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
}

- (IBAction)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^
                     {
                         _googleLoginBackButton.frame = CGRectMake(168, 700, 40, 40);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {
                         [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                                               delay:0.45
                                             options:0
                                          animations:^
                                          {
                                              _googleLoginBackButton.frame = CGRectMake(168, 564, 40, 40);
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished)
                                          {
                                          }
                          ];
                     }
     ];
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (!error)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toHome" sender:self];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: seems like you segued  from storyboard , and also from code. Keep any one.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean? The only segues in here are outgoing segues. The segues to enter this view controller are implemented in the storyboard's GUI creation area, there is no programatically-made entrance segue.

Answer (score 0):

For any of you as neglectful as I am, double check the implementation of the controller that navigates to this one. I found that I had a manual segue in the actual GUI Storyboard area that navigated to a controller on the press of a button, however I also implemented a segue programatically. The simple solution is to convert the GUI Storyboard segue into one that links between controllers, not between actions and controllers.